# passing js parameter with apostrophe html code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asciiencoding

```
<a title="Delete" onclick="remove_file('folder', 4493,'Colin&#39;s folder')"><i class="icon-trash" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></a>
```

The above code has the html code `&#39;` to represent an apostrophe in the string. In Google Chrome, I am currently getting the following error from that line:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected Identifier

I assume that one of those characters is breaking the parsing?  I have other instances of this same code without the apostrophe code and I do not get the error. How can I fix this, while still being able to pass strings with apostrophes?

Comment: Can you post the `remove_file` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
'Colin\'s folder'
```

instead? Javascript understands backslash escapes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just escape it like the following:

```
onclick="remove_file('folder', 4493,'Colin\'s folder')"
```

See the following jsbin with an alert:
http://jsbin.com/axuyun/1/